# Python slice/chunk an iterator obj

Tags: python, iterator

I am trying to chunk an iterator object but keep getting a `maximum recursion depth error`.  I tried to simulate a simplest example below.

So assume there is a subprocess reading endless stream of json lines.  I then want the object to return dictionary for each of the lines.  Technically, since each line from the subprocess is a valid json, I can just do `json.loads()` for each and that will return a dictionary already.  Unfortunately, converting each line to a dictionary is slow and it is faster to load a chunk, say 10,000 json lines into one big dictionary (order kept), then iterate that over.

How can I make this sample code work accordingly?  I have set a `_next()` here since I can have different functions, depending on some parameters/features.

Keep in mind, for this example I could have also used `jsonlines.Reader()` and read this .txt, but this is just an example.  Assume this will be some streamed data from somewhere, and also assume it will be quite a lot of data.  I also find `jsonlines.Reader` to be slower than reading a chunk with `json.loads()`

Sample code:

```
import subprocess
from itertools import islice
import json

NUM_CHUNKS = 10_000


class Sub:
    def __init__(self, cmd: str):
        self.p = subprocess.Popen(
            cmd,
            shell=True,
            executable="/bin/bash",
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
        self.curr_gen = None
        self._next = self.stream_dict

    def set_gen(self):
        ## Just reading/converting each line
        # line = self.p.stdout.readline()
        # d = json.loads(line)
        # yield d

        ## Chunking version
        chunk = islice(self, NUM_CHUNKS)
        if not chunk:
            return
        data = "[" + ",".join([line for line in chunk]) + "]"
        d = json.loads(data)
        for line_obj in d:
            yield line_obj

    def stream_dict(self):
        try:
            line = next(self.curr_gen)
            return line
        except:
            self.curr_gen = self.set_gen()
            return next(self.curr_gen)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self._next()


r = Sub("cat sample_jsonlines.txt")

for dict_lines in r:
    print(dict_lines)
```

Where `sample_jsonlines.txt` has something like

```
{"somecol1": "xxxx", "somecol2": "yyyy"}
{"somecol1": "xxxx", "somecol2": "yyyy"}
{"somecol1": "xxxx", "somecol2": "yyyy"}
```

I added some commented code under set_gen, if it was just to read one line at a time and convert to dictionary (without chunking).

Comment: How much faster is handling that 10000 lines chunk than handling the lines individually?

Comment: I cant get the code working really, but having a txt of 100,000 json lines and converting each lines to dictionary takes about 5 times slower than just reading the entire thing with json.loads(), then iterating through each of the dictionary, line by line. Hence, I am assuming it will be faster to chunk it with a certain chunksize

Comment: For starters, I would not be a bare except clause like that.

Comment: `if not chunk:` will *never be true*, an `islice` object is always truthy. You would have to convert this to a list or something for this to work the way you expect. So I suspect that is why you are getting a recursion error. Not sure there is any need to use recursion anyway, and you probably shouldn't if you expect the depth to be large to begin with

Comment: Although, it should terminate eventually when it reaches the end of the generator function. The fundamental issue is you cannot use recursion here, I think, if you expect an infinite stream